# How I can navegate and see in all pages and see the events of the app.components?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to use tokens towards the backend  and I'm doing the validations in the app.components.ts file. However, when I use  navigateRoot or  router.navigate, I don't see the validations I have in the app.component.

This is my code:

```
export class AppComponent {

 constructor( ) {

   this.initializeApp();

 }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.info('test 1');
    
  }

initializeApp() {

//the events

}

}
```

For example, 'test 1' only I see when the page is reload, but when I navegate between pages this value isn't show.

How I can  navegate and see in all pages and see the events of the app.components?

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code you can listen to all route events in the tab from app.component

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
         console.log(val); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but  It's show me for each page a value in log.  Is it correct to manage the tokens from the app.component app?  or  .  should I have a token control for each page?

Comment: if token control is what you aim for then better look at https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/angular-9-router-canactivate-guards-urltree-parsed-routes/

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want to do token control in a component. It's better to create a guard with CanActivate method for the root component (possibly, for AppComponent in your case). See for example this post https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3.